# How can I map a lat/long to the nearest point of my polygon/shapefile in R

Tags: r, geometry, gis, latitude-longitude, shapefile

I am trying to map a set of lats/longs to my shape file to obtain CSDUID/census divisions information.

However, there are some outliers or lat/longs that are outside of the shapefile. I was wondering if it would be possible to map those points to the nearest point of the shapefile so that I can obtain division information for the later part of my analysis?

## Reproducible example

Let's say I have a shapefile like `gr`

```r
nc <- st_transform(st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")), 2264)                
gr = st_sf(
    label = apply(expand.grid(1:10, LETTERS[10:1])[,2:1], 1, paste0, collapse = " "),
    geom = st_make_grid(nc))

# gr
# Simple feature collection with 100 features and 1 field
# geometry type:  POLYGON
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 406262.2 ymin: 48374.87 xmax: 3052887 ymax: 1044158
# epsg (SRID):    2264
# proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=36.16666666666666 +lat_2=34.33333333333334 +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +x_0=609601.2192024384 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs
# First 10 features:
#    label                           geom
# 1   J  1 POLYGON ((406262.2 48374.87...
# 2   J  2 POLYGON ((670924.7 48374.87...
# 3   J  3 POLYGON ((935587.2 48374.87...
# 4   J  4 POLYGON ((1200250 48374.87,...
# 5   J  5 POLYGON ((1464912 48374.87,...
# 6   J  6 POLYGON ((1729575 48374.87,...
# 7   J  7 POLYGON ((1994237 48374.87,...
# 8   J  8 POLYGON ((2258900 48374.87,...
# 9   J  9 POLYGON ((2523562 48374.87,...
# 10  J 10 POLYGON ((2788225 48374.87,...
```

And I have a point that is outside the bounding box:

```r
point = st_point(c(106160,28370))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = gr) + geom_sf(data = point)
```

[image]

How can I map points to the closest polygon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have great functions for spatial analysis, especially spatial joins, in `sf` package. Assuming your point data are named `point` and your polygons are named.... `polygons` (both `sf` objects), you can use `sf::st_join` for spatial joins.

`st_join` accepts different types of spatial mapping. I think you are interested in `st_nearest_feature` merge (first remove points that fall within your polygons, e.g. by a first `st_join` using `st_within`)

```r
library(sf)

st_join(
  points,
  polygons,
  join = st_nearest_feature
)
```

In the edited example, that would give:

```r
point = st_sf(st_sfc(point), crs = st_crs(gr))
st_join(point, gr, join = st_nearest_feature)
```

see `?st_join` doc.

Comment: st_join with st_nearest_feature worked perfectly. Thanks!